# Trying to get the results of a function to populate the parameters of a class Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file which is calling a class. I want to take the results of a function in that javascript file and pass it as the parameters of that class. I want to take the results of the "convertGeoLocation" function and pass the value into the "Weather" object.

```
    // Init weather object
    const weather = new Weather();
    const ui = new UI();
    const convertTypedLocation = new Convert('Redding', 'CA');


    // Get weaterh on DOM load
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);
    // Get geolocation on load
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', convertGeoLocation);

    function getWeather() {
    weather.getWeather()
        .then(results => {

            // ui.paint(results);
            console.log(results);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    // function getGeoLocation() {
    //     getLocation.getGeo()
    //     .then(geoResults => {
    //         ui.getLocation(geoResults);
    //         // console.log(geoResults);
    //     })
    //     .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // }

    function convertGeoLocation() {
        convertTypedLocation.convertLocation()
        .then(convertResults => {
           latitude = convertResults.results[0].geometry.lat;
           console.log(latitude);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertGeoLocation() {
    convertTypedLocation.convertLocation()
    .then(convertResults => {
       weather.results = convertResults;
       latitude = convertResults.results[0].geometry.lat;
       console.log(latitude);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not the proper way of doing it.
It's usually better to create a new method in the weather object like so :

```
addResults(results) {
    this.results = results
}
```

and then adding it via this method :

```
function convertGeoLocation() {
    convertTypedLocation.convertLocation()
    .then(convertResults => {
       weather.addResults(convertResults);
       latitude = convertResults.results[0].geometry.lat;
       console.log(latitude);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Angel. Once I get it added to weather object how do I use the results to populate the constructor variables. I want to take the latitude and longitude result that I receive and populate them into my constructor so that way when it makes the call to the API it adds the latitude and longitude into the fetch URL.